# Can I create a line that lies exactly in the middle between two abstract polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-pro

Effectively, I need to buffer around two nearby abstract polygons, without any overlap, with each buffer ending at the midpoint between the two polygons. If I can create a line that lies between the polygons, I can use that line to erase each buffer as appropriate.

Comment: Density lines and create voronoi's polygons, or do euclidean allocation.

Comment: I don’t think this needs ArcPy and is much easier to do with ArcGIS Pro than ArcMap so if you remove the ArcPy and ArcMap tags, and focus it on ArcGIS Pro, then I’ll write an answer to it.

Comment: Also, a picture of your input polygons and desired output, what you are wanting will be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit daunting to do such operation in ArcMap as the tool that can do this only work on lines as far as I know, but here is how you can achieve the middle line between two polygons

1-*"Polygon To Line" tool*: Convert the two polys to line.

2-*"Merge" tool*: Merge the two new polylines layers.

3- *Edit toolbar*:  use the *split tool* in the edit tool bar to split the two facing lines of each polygon. then delete the rest of the lines (keep only the two facing lines).

4- *"Collapse Dual Lines To Centerline"* tool : using this tool will get you the centerline. It's recommended to use a maximum width parameter a bit larger than the maximum distance between the lines, but it works just fine in most cases.
[image]